# How to set FitNesse never expire?

Tags: wiki, fitnesse

Hallo,

When I start the FitNesse server, I have the following output:

> FitNesse (v20091210) Started...
>           port:              8080
>           root page:         fitnesse.wiki.FileSystemPage at
>   ./FitNesseRoot
>           logger:            none
>           authenticator:     fitnesse.authentication.PromiscuousAuthenticator
>           html page factory: fitnesse.html.HtmlPageFactory
>           page version expiration set to 14 days.

Notice that the page version expiration set to 14 days, what does it mean by expiration? Is that mean the server will stop in 14 days? Can I set it to never expire?

THanks @!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you change a page in FitNesse it keeps a backup copy of the previous version. The backup copy will be kept for 14 days.  The server doesn't expire, just the backup copies.